# unable to run javascript public function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I am createing Canvas CreateJS based drag and drop quiz, the error is when I drop any object then I need to run a function goback() which is available in that class but I dn't know why it's not accessible.

http://www.fltech.in/canvas/dragndrop/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: Questions about code nearly ALWAYS should include the relevant code right in the question.  External links as the only source of code are not permitted here on StackOverflow.  Since it appears you may be new here, you may benefit from reading: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your `dropbox` function, `this` no longer refers to the outside scope. You can change all `this.a =` to `var a`, and use `goback()` directly in `dropbox` rather than using `this.goback()`.

You can refer to http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/ for more information about `this` in javascript.

Comment: I have tried to access goback() function directly before posting my query to stackoverflow but it's not accessible on that case as well.

Comment: @user3113899 you should change all `this.dropbox = function` to `var dropbox = function`, `this.init = function` to `var init`....